# Email's being sent to @privaterelay.appleid.com - how do I access?

Tags: email, apple-id

I bought a few concert tickets on stubhub, but I think because I created an account through apple my email is set to a long random string "@privaterelay.appleid.com", so all of my tickets are being sent to this account and I have no other way to access them. Before I get on the phone with stubhub customer service, I would like to try and log on to this email to access my tickets.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210426#change https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210426#turnoffemail test by sending an email yourself to your relay  ID

Comment: It turns out I already this address set up to forward to my personal email